# How to disable auctex fontification, without losing color highlighting?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I like maximum syntax highlighting of AucTeX, but I don't like AucTeX messing with fonts. For example, if I use italics, it shows italicized letters in my emacs buffer, and shows subscripts and superscripts in small letters (slightly above or below the line). I prefer to use a fixed width font regardless of the latex environment I am in.

I tried changing the settings for the variable font-latex-deactivated-keyword-classes, but then the syntax coloring also disappears.

Could someone suggest a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Faces.html#Faces

In case you want to change the colors and fonts used by font-latex please refer to the faces mentioned in the explanations above and use `M-x customize-face RET <face> RET`. All faces defined by font-latex are accessible through a customization group by typing

> M-x customize-group RET font-latex-highlighting-faces RET.

---

The above command opens the settings buffer where you can set the appropriate font face. Once you save changes, your .emacs file will contain a line similar to:

> '(font-latex-sectioning-5-face ((((class color) (background light))
>   (:inherit variable-pitch :foreground "blue4" :weight normal :foundry
>   "outline" :family "Century Gothic")

In your example, you can customize the `Font Latex Italic Face` to your specifications. Your .emacs should then contain

> '(font-latex-italic-face ...)

to whatever you set it to. You can similarly customize superscript, subscript and whole host of other font faces.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of AUCTeX:

```
(setq font-latex-fontify-script nil)
(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 'color)
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this page in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Fontification-of-macros.html) and the section *Deactivating defaults of built-in keyword classes*.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Emacs 24.3.  Put the following in your ~/.emacs file:

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(font-latex-bold-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-doctex-documentation-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-doctex-preprocessor-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-italic-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-math-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-sectioning-0-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-sectioning-1-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-sectioning-2-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-sectioning-3-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-sectioning-4-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-sectioning-5-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-sedate-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-slide-title-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-string-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-subscript-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-superscript-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-verbatim-face ((t nil)))
 '(font-latex-warning-face ((t nil))))
```